# type error 'str' object is not callable in python

Tags: python

```
import pickle
from array import array
class person:
    def __init__(self, name,last_name,address,tell,course,uni_name):
        self.name=name
        self.last_name=last_name
        self.address=address
        self.tell=tell
        self.course=course
        self.uni_name=uni_name



class student(person):
    def __init__(self,name,last_name,address,tell,course,uni_name,score,avrage):
        person.__init__(self,name,last_name,address,tell,course,uni_name)
        self.score = score
        self.avrage = avrage

    def avrage(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0, 3):
            sum += self.score[i]
        ave = sum / 3
        return ave

    def info(self):
        self.name=input("enter your name: ")
        self.last_name = input("enter your last name: ")
        self.address = input("enter your address: ")
        self.tell= int(input("enter your tell: "))
        self.uni_name = input("enter student univercity: ")
        self.course = input("enter student course: ")
        for i in range(0, 3):
            self.score.append(float(input("enter student score " + str(i + 1) + ":")))
        self.ave=self.avrage()
        return self

    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.last_name,self.address,self.tell,self.course,self.uni_name,self.score,self.ave)






def write_file(list1, n):
    file = open('D:\\STUD', 'wb')
    for i in range(n):
        pickle.dump(list1[i], file)
    file.close()



def read_file(n):
    student = []
    file = open('D:\\STUD', 'rb')
    for i in range(n):
        student.append(pickle.load(file))
    file.close()
    return student




def Sort_name(list_name, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_name[i].name > list_name[j].name:
                temp = list_name[i]
                list_name[i] = list_name[j]
                list_name[j] = temp


def Sort_last(list_lastname, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_lastname[i].last_name > list_lastname[j].last_name:
                temp = list_lastname[i]
                list_lastname[i] = list_lastname[j]
                list_lastname[j] = temp


def Sort_add(list_address, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_address[i].address > list_address[j].address:
                temp = list_address[i]
                list_address[i] = list_address[j]
                list_address[j] = temp


def Sort_te(list_tell, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_tell[i].tell > list_tell[j].tell:
                temp = list_tell[i]
                list_tell[i] = list_tell[j]
                list_tell[j] = temp


def Sort_co(list_course, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_course[i].tell > list_course[j].tell:
                temp = list_course[i]
                list_course[i] = list_course[j]
                list_course[j] = temp


def Sort_un(list_uniname, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_uniname[i].tell > list_uniname[j].tell:
                temp = list_uniname[i]
                list_uniname[i] = list_uniname[j]
                list_uniname[j] = temp


def Sort_sc(list_score, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if list_score[i].score > list_score[j].score:
                temp = list_score[i]
                list_score[i] = list_score[j]
                list_score[j] = temp


stu_list=[]

for i in range(0,3):
    stu=student("","" ,"","","","",[],"" )
    stu.info()

    stu_list.append(stu)


write_file(stu_list,3)

Sort_name(stu_list,1)
Sort_last(stu_list,1)
Sort_add(stu_list,1)
Sort_te(stu_list,1)
Sort_co(stu_list,1)
Sort_un(stu_list,1)
Sort_sc(stu_list,1)

stu_list=read_file(3)

for i in range(0,3):
    stu_list[i].show()
```

Comment: format the code above better and tell what line the error is on

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: Don't use `sum` for a variable name, since doing so will mask the builtin function of that name.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `student` class.  It's using `avrage` as both an instance variable name and a method name.  The effect of this is that the instance variable overrides the method, making the method uncallable.

In `__init__`, it does:

```
      self.avrage = avrage
```

And it also defines a method with that name:

```
    def avrage(self):
```

So when you try to call `avrage()`, it is instead picking up the instance variable, which is a string rather than a method.

You can fix it by renaming one of them so they have different names.

Comment: The `info()` method calls it `self.ave`. That's probably what it should use in `__init__`.

Comment: It's also unclear why this needs to be a parameter of the class, or why they're passing a string instead of number for it.